# Insert Data to MongoDB with Kafka-MongoDB-Connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb

I'm trying to insert data from a Kafka topic to a MongoDB database with Kafka-MongoDB-Connect.

The Kafka Connect properties file:

```
group.id=stage
offset.storage.topic=stage_offset
config.storage.topic=stage_config
status.storage.topic=stage_status
bootstrap.servers=****************:9092
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
rest.host.name=localhost
rest.port=9002
plugin.path=/mnt/d/confluent-5.2.1/plugins
offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
```

The data in the Kafka topic:

```
1557408134887 | 7316|+|2019-05-09 | 7316 | 2019-05-09 | 249.35999999999999
1557408134941 | 6110|+|2019-05-09 | 6110 | 2019-05-09 | 3321.0399999999995
1557408135199 | 11688|+|2019-05-09 | 11688 | 2019-05-09 | 3261.800000000001
1557408134603 | 55247|+|2019-05-09 | 55247 | 2019-05-09 |995.4200000000002
```

And this is the FORMATJSON:

```
{"STOREID":3194,"BUSINESSDATE":"2019-05-09","CA":"1.82"}
{"STOREID":4479,"BUSINESSDATE":"2019-05-09","CA":"7.71"}
{"STOREID":6818,"BUSINESSDATE":"2019-05-09","CA":"121.69"}
{"STOREID":9127,"BUSINESSDATE":"2019-05-09","CA":"67.82"}
{"STOREID":4987,"BUSINESSDATE":"2019-05-09","CA":"40.56"}
{"STOREID":1654,"BUSINESSDATE":"2019-05-09","CA":"26.94"}
```

The MongoDB connector:

```
{
    "name": "mongo-sink-connector",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.MongoDbSinkConnector",
        "tasks.max": "1",
        "topics": "VENTE_PDV_JOUR",
        "mongodb.connection.uri": "mongodb://localhost:27018/stage-project?w=1&journal=true",
        "mongodb.value.projection.type": "whitelist",
        "mongodb.value.projection.list":"STOREID,BUSINESSDATE,CA",
        "mongodb.collection": "ticket-data",
        "flush.size": "100",
        "rotate.interval.ms": "1000",
        "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": false,
        "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": false
    }
}
```

but I get this error :

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images where you could post text, it makes it much harder to read your question. Can you update your question with the actual KSQL and topic output as text please?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Done

Comment: try `"value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"`

Comment: the same error -> Invalid JSON number

Comment: can you edit your question to include the full stack trace from your Kafka Connect Worker log?

Comment: i add the properties file if it can help

Comment: Nope, need to see the complete relevant section of the log / stacktrace from the Kafka Connect worker, in which you're finding the error you quote

Comment: i add a picture for the error @RobinMoffatt